# If Statement in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a task to list students' details. I want to perform searching based on name and city. If `cityId==0 and name=''`, then I want to list all my student details. How can I do this? I did this in a wrong way. The controller is:

```
    if(Student.where(params[:cityId])==0)
    studentcount = Student.count()
    @students = Student.limit(params[:jtPageSize]).offset(params[:jtStartIndex]).order(params[:jtSorting])
    @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Records' => @students.map(&:attributes), :TotalRecordCount => studentcount}
    else
    studentcount = Student.where("name LIKE ? AND city = ?", "%#{params[:name]}%", params[:cityId]).count()
    @students = Student.where("name LIKE ? AND city = ?", "%#{params[:name]}%", params[:cityId]).limit(params[:jtPageSize]).offset(params[:jtStartIndex]).order(params[:jtSorting])
    @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Records' => @students.map(&:attributes), :TotalRecordCount => studentcount}
```

Comment: As a note, if you're using Rails, the convention is to name things `city_id` and not `cityID`. Camel-case is pretty much only used for class names.

Comment: too much code for a controller, move to the model everything except a one-line data retriever and the respond_to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should look like this:

```
 if( Student.where(:cityId => params[:cityId]).count == 0 )
```

The if-statement you have tests a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and an Integer for equality which will never be true

Comment: Error is occuring like this, unexpected 
 ':'

Comment: your are using ruby 1.8 right, then you have to use the old hashrocket syntax - `:cityId => params[:cityId]`

Comment: you can safely remove those parens. Yes, they are in the question, but they are absolutely unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if User.where(city_id: params[:cityId]).empty?
```